# GLSL не работают циклы

Tags: webgl, glsl

В GLSL не получается создать шейдер с циклом:

```
do{
}while();
и
while(){
}
```

в чем может быть проблема?
Вершинный шейдер:

```
attribute vec3 a_Position; \
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix; \
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix; \
varying vec3 v_Position; \
varying float v_Alpha; \
float residue( float a, float b ) { \
    float c = ceil( a/b ); \
    return a-c*b; \
} \
void main( ) { \
float alpha = .0; \
float scale = 1.0; \
if ( residue( a_Position.x, 24.0 ) != .0 || residue( a_Position.z, 24.0 ) != .0 ) { \
    vec4 camera = u_MVPMatrix * vec4( .0, .0, .0, 1.0 ); \
    float distance = sqrt( camera.x*camera.x + camera.y*camera.y + camera.z*camera.z ); \
    while ( alpha <= .0 ) { \
        alpha = 1.0 - distance / ( 200.0 * scale ); \
        scale *= 4.0; \
    } \
        scale /= 4.0; \
    }else{ \
        alpha = 1.0; \
    } \
    v_Alpha = alpha; \
    v_Position = a_Position * scale; \
    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * u_MVMatrix * vec4( v_Position, 1.0 ); \
}
```

В чем же тут ошибка?

Comment: Вы можете получить лог компиляции шейдера, там будет написана ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по обрывкам документации, WebGL версия GLSL может не поддерживать непредсказуемые циклы (такие в которых компилятор не может заранее подсчитать число итераций).

В вашем цикле нельзя заранее предсказать, сколько в нем будет итераций, 1, 10, миллион.

```
while ( alpha <= .0 ) { \
    alpha = 1.0 - distance / ( 200.0 * scale ); \
    scale *= 4.0; \
}
```

Попробуйте добавить предсказуемый выход (тут уж зависит от компилятора, что он посчитает предсказуемым, а что нет) или используйте цикл for.